# Wireless debugging of windows mobile applications

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, windows-vista, wireless

I'm trying to debug a windows mobile aplication using a wifi connection, on a Vista with Visual Studio 2008 following this instruction http://blogs.msdn.com/vsdteam/archive/2005/04/28/413304.aspx.

It worked flawlessly with XP SP2, but not with Vista. Do you know if this is possible at all? or is another flaw from Vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine.  I debug to a CE 5.0 device from Studio '08 on Vista quite regularly.  I use the same general outline of steps (though i do use a tool that automates the process).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure out what is wrong with my setup then. I'm using Vista Home Premium perhaps is something missing there...

Comment: Make sure that the version of conmanclient2.exe is the same on the device and the PC.  Thats the most common problem.  To ensure it is, manually copy it from the CoreCon folder on the PC.

Comment: Look here for the binaries:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\1.0\Target\wce400